# Parse string from AJAX Success to run as JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On my HTML page, I have an AJAX Post to get some data. The returned data contains a string, and the content of this string is raw javascript.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetPropertyDataForInstance", "Local_Data")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: instancePropertyRequest,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (response) {

        var javscriptRawString = response.javascriptToExecute;   
        var alertString = response.data;
    }
})
```

The content of javscriptRawString:

```
alert(alertString);
```

After I get this javascriptRawString, what do I do so that I can directly execute the javascript inside??

Comment: That's what `eval` does.  Beware of security holes.

Comment: Rather than return script and `eval` it (which is a security nightmare, and really nasty code), why not return the string `hello there` and `alert` it within the `success` handler.

Comment: I really doubt that 'hello there' alert is the code he wants in the end.  Probably just to test the response.  But ya... if you can do anything to avoid `eval`, do it.  And chances are you can easily avoid `eval`

Comment: if you pass in a function name you could execute it using `window[javscriptRawString]();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is slightly better than eval as eval is evil ;)

```
(new Function(response.data))()
```

Using `eval` is evil because there can be lots of security holes. You are executing code in global scope. `Function` takes of this differently by executing in its own scope.

`new Function` is also faster

in your case

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetPropertyDataForInstance", "Local_Data")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: instancePropertyRequest,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (response) {

        (new Function(response.data))()   

    }
})
```

`new Function` creates a new function from a raw text.

`()()` executes the function immediately

i would also add some extra checks and headers if you get your functions with ajax.
check this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17468822/2450730

edit

if you want to pass params from ajax

```
//raw ajax response
var x='param';
alert(x)
```

if you want to pass params from inside the ajax (not good.)

```
success: function (response) {
 var x='param';
 (new Function(response.data))(x)   
}
```

raw

```
alert(x);
```

**edit 2**

if you get a object with
1.the script
2.the params

then you need to define a argument name.in this case 'x'.

js

```
 (new Function('x',response.script))(response.param)
```

RAW response.script

```
 alert(x)
```

more arguments:

```
(new Function('a','b','c','alert(a+b+c)'))(1,2,3) // 123
```

**TEST IT** ... http://jsfiddle.net/pLQzd/
**READ IT** ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function
scroll to the bottom.

but as you get the object containing the function and the vars... from the same ajax call

i would simply create something already described.

RAW

```
var param='hello';
alert(param);
```

or even simpler

```
alert('hello');
```

Comment: If there's data in the that I need to pass into the new generated function, how do I do that? I understand (new Function(response.data))() creates a new function based on the string in response.data, but how do I pass a parameter in there? I tried (new Function(response.data))(anotherVar), but this doesn't work :(

Comment: what you mean ? extend you question...from where you getthe params?

Comment: I mean I want to pass a variable into this newly generated function. In this function I need this variable to perform some other assignments.

Comment: ajaxRaw: var x='banana';alert(x)

Comment: In my response, it's list of objects. These objects have a key and value. 
So in this case, I have two objects in the response. 

One object is key="script", value="return 5 + valueForFunction;" 
The other object has the data, key="data", value=1. 

So this is something that I want to do: 
var functionString = response.data.get("script");
var valueForFunction = response.data.get("data");
var myFunction = (new Function(functionString));
myFunction(valueForFunction);

Comment: post a example raw response by extending your question.

Comment: I edited the original question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please clarify x??

Comment: function (x) {alert(x)} ... x is just the name for the first argument.more arguments : (new Function('a','b','c','alert(a+b+c)'))(1,2,3)

Answer (score 2):

You can run any string via `eval`:

```
eval('alert("hello world")');
```

Make sure you know exactly what you're evaling though.

Comment: "Make sure you know exactly what you're evaling though."

Comment: Yes, I've read that. Still, I would be careful recommending `eval`, especially to beginners, since they are all too likely to ignore any disclaimers and warnings..

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not format your ajax response with integers?

e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    //Your AJAX
}).done(function(response) {
    //Let's say response from the script is 1.

    switch(response) {
        case 1:
            alert('Hello world');
            break;

        //case ... etc.
    }

});
```

NEVER use `eval();` unless you have absolutely no other choice.

eval === evil!

Comment: There is almost always a better method than using `eval`.  If we knew his actual problem and not this made-up problem I'm sure we could give him a proper answer...

Comment: "Why would you not format your ajax response with integers?" Why **would** you?

Comment: @nzifnab you are entirely correct, lets just hope the OP follows this example to start with and to avoid `eval();`ling possibly viscious code.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist because scripts, for instance when handling database requests could easily return an integer to work with and is very easy to identify, ofcourse if you expect a response with data, use JSON to return it, but in this particular case, we do not know what the OP needs.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this "potentially massive switch statement" and some obscure number code that does magical things.  But there's no reason you can't return a JSON data structure and perform actions based on that

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand They could also easily return pretty much anything else. There's zero reason to suggest that returning an integer that's arbitrarily mapped to a string of code using a `switch` statement is a better, or even good, approach.

Comment: I never mentioned 'better' or 'good', And as mentioned, we do not know what the OP gets back, hence the integer, there is no downside to using one either, just a suggestion for further processing anyways. and if an Ajax call returns alot of different responses, I'd recommend using a function that handles ajax responses rather than a switch statement.